# Angular - Include Headers file

Tags: angular

I have to include header files in my project for authentication purpose but when I am trying to include it , it is giving error
Error:Failed to load https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hi: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

**xyz.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XyzService {
    word: String = "aardvark";
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.throw(err.message);
    }
    getDictonaryData(name?): any {
        if (name) {
            this.word = name
        }
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('app_id', '*****');
        headers.append('app_key', '7d0740a12*******bc66907835843d6f');


        let myResponse = this._http.get('https://od- 
       api.oxforddictionaries.com / api / v1 / entries / en / ' + this.word);
       return myResponse;

    }
}
```

> app.comoonent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { XyzService } from './xyz.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    name: string;
    dictData: any;


    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
     xyzService: XyzService, ) { }

    getData() {
        this.xyzService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
            data => {

                this.dictData = data;
                console.log(this.dictData);
            },

            error => {
                console.log("some error occured");
                console.log(error.errorMessage);
            }
        );

    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
<button (click)="getData()"> Get Data </button>

<div class="row" *ngIf="dictData">
    <h2>{{dictData["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0] ["definitions"]}}

    </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oxford dictionaries API currently does not support CORS** (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

Instead they recommend to make the query reach user's server side application, and then send the API request from the user's server to oxford's server rather than directly from the client.

So it's not possible to directly send API requests to their server.

It is mentioned in [Oxford forum discussion](https://forum.oxforddictionaries.com/api/discussion/comment/135) by an administrator.

But you can easily bypass your requests through your server.

> For php implementation in Apache

Use [GuzzleHttp](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) for easy PHP implementation

> For Node Server

Use [Request](https://github.com/request/request) or [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) package
I have added a **solution** for **Node server** implemention. 
You can find it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053713/angular-bypass-the-requests-through-the-server/51070117#51070117)

But I suggest not to use CORS plugins or browser tweaks. As they causes security breaches and also cannot be used as a permanent solution

Comment: I am using node server . Can you please help me ,how to implement Request package in my code .

Comment: Sure, but I will suggest you to create another post with your query for node implementation. So that others can also contribute.
And if you are satisfied with these solution, you can mark it as an accepted one. Thanks

Comment: I have marked your solution as an accepted one . please give me the solution for 'how to implement Request package in my code'. I need it very urgently due to project deadline . .

Comment: Due to project deadline, i don't have enough time to create other post and wait for others contribution . So, Sir Please help me on answering my question .

Comment: It doesn't take much time to ask a new question. And it will be easier to post a formatted answer instead of raw comments.

Comment: I had posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053713/angular-bypass-the-requests-through-the-server . Please answer it . I also request you to please check your code that wheather it is working or not before answering to my question .

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this

```
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.set('Accept','application/json');
  headers.set('app_id','4ebde091');
  headers.set('app_key','7d0740a128b7e39bbc66907835843d6f');
  let myResponse = this._http.get('someurl',{
   headers: headers
  });
```

Comment: let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set('Accept','application/json');
      headers.set('app_id','4ebde091');
      headers.set('app_key','7d0740a128b7e39bbc66907835843d6f');


  let myResponse = this._http.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/'+this.word,{headers: headers});
  return myResponse;    It is giving me error:zone.js:2969 GET https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hi 403

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new Headers();
```

Should be

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

As `Headers` are deprecated now, so you need to use `HttpHeaders` instead.

For more information read out here -

- https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers
- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

you are access live api from localhost so domain is diffrent.

you can add this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Extensions

[Intall Extension and keep ON](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Comment: I added it . Now i am getting error : GET https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hey 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: you have Enable CORS from browser top-right corner.

Comment: toggle off and ON

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the extension to resolve this issue.
1.if you are using `chrome` browser 'Moesif Origin & CORS Changer' extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) 
2.if you are using `Firefox` browser then you can install from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/spenibus/?src=api)

Comment: I added it . Now i am getting error : GET od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hey 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: @Rishav have you tested API in postman or another third party tool on which working or not?

Comment: @Rishav if in postman api is working fine then check your .htaccess file configuration as well if apache is allowing or not for accessing .htaccess