# Angular - bypass the requests through the server

Tags: angular

It is mentioned that Oxford dictionary api (https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com) does not support CORS .Instead they recommend to make the query reach user's server side application, and then send the API request from the user's server to oxford's server rather than directly from the client. So it's not possible to directly send API requests to their server. So, What changes i need to make in my code in order to fetch the data from their api . Also i don't want to use proxy configuration or CORS plugins or browser tweaks. As they causes security breaches and also cannot be used as a permanent solution .

xyz.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class XyzService {

   word: String = "aardvark";
   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
   private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
   console.log(err.message);
   return Observable.throw(err.message);
   }
  getDictonaryData(name?): any {
      if(name){
      this.word = name
  }

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('app_id','4eb****91');
  headers.append('app_key','7d0740a128***9bbc66907835843d6f');

let myResponse = this._http.get('https://od- 
api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/'+this.word,{headers: headers
  });
 return myResponse;

 } 
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { XyzService } from './xyz.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 name:string;
 dictData:any;


constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
xyzService: XyzService, ) {}

getData() {
  this.xyzService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
    data => {

        this.dictData = data;
          console.log(this.dictData);
          } ,

      error => {
          console.log("some error occured");
          console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
  );

 }}
```

app.component.html

```
 <input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
 <button (click)="getData()"> Get Data </button>

 <div class="row" *ngIf="dictData">
 <h2>{{dictData["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0] 
["definitions"]}}

</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to create your own **server** side method (nodejs, php, whatever server language) that will fetch the data from the remote url. Then you implement CORS (if needed) on that server side method

Answer (score 0):

For **Node Server**

> Step - 1 : Install **url**

```
npm install url
```

> Step - 2 : **Save the script**

script.js

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var my_app_id;
var my_app_key;
var mainRes;

// Recieve get request from client
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  mainRes = res;
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true); // true to get query as object
  var params = parsedUrl.pathname;

  my_app_id = JSON.stringify(req.headers.app_id).replace(/\"/g, "");
  my_app_key = JSON.stringify(req.headers.app_key).replace(/\"/g, "");
  var word_id = params.substring(1);

  if (word_id && my_app_id && my_app_key) {
    // Proper Request
    var options = {
            host: 'od-api.oxforddictionaries.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/api/v1/entries/en/'+word_id,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'app_key' : my_app_key,
            'app_id' : my_app_id
        }
    }; 
    console.log("Start");
    var x = https.request(options,function(res){
        console.log("Connected");
        var responseString = "";
        res.on('data',function(data){
            responseString += data;
        });
        res.on("end", function () {
            console.log(responseString); 
            mainRes.end(responseString);
            // print to console when response ends
        });
    });

    x.end();
  } else {
    res.end("Request not proper");
  }

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

> Step - 3 : Run it

```
node script.js
```

> Step - 4 : Send Get request with headers

Example : For word "hello"
Get Request should be http://yourdomain.com:1337/hello
 or http://yourserverip:1337/hello
With headers app_id and app_key